# SharedPreferences int not updated after apply

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am running:

```
int value = mPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
mPreferences.edit().putInt(key, value+1).apply();
int newValue = return mPreferences.getInt(key, 0);
```

However I get the same result for `value` and `newValue`. The updated result only appears when I call `getInt()` later in the code. I thought updates to the `SharedPreferences` object using `apply()` would instantly be visible in the `SharedPreferences` object. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you want synchronous update you have to use

```
commit()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()

Comment: with commit you can check if the datas were successfully written to persistent storage

Comment: Yes, in that case commit() returns true, but the get right after returns the old value.

Comment: If commit() returned true, it has written the new value. Maybe you have some problems with the right value of your "value"

Comment: I'm just doing a +1 operation, so it should definitely be different

Answer (score 0):

First of all `commit()` & `apply()` are the almost the same, major difference been that `apply()` is faster

I tried doing it the same way & it worked for me
Check this :

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    int a = sharedPreferences.getInt("a",0);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "a = " + a , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("a", a+1).apply();
```

After checking the xml in data of the app, I got `a` as 1